# UI thread issue

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, bluetooth

I've been developing a few basic Android apps recently and notice a slightly odd behaviour which I'm sure is my own wrong doing.

The problem seems to lie with the main thread which I'm using for both updating the UI and some processing such as sending a message via Bluetooth.

Let's say I have the following:

```
public void sendMessage(){
  updateUI();
  sendBtMessage();
}

public void updateUI(){
  txtView.setText("Sending message");
  progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void sendBTmessage(){
... connect to BT and send message here
}
```

As I run my code it appears to be running sendBtMessage first as the UI update appears after the message is sent(I would like it before sending the message). Is this because the main threads priority is to do the heaviest work-load first?

Should the main thread be used for only updating the UI?

Any Suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: please post the code that is performed in sendBTmessage. The answer really depends on how you're connecting

Comment: From what callback methods you call each of those functions?

Comment: also where are you calling sendMessage() from.  it might be a good idea to have asyncTasks  for any labor intensive tasks so your UI is not bottle necked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to handle the sendBTMessage on a new thread such as:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
      ...processing   
    }
}).start();
```

and the UI runs smoothly using

```
RunOnUiThread(Runnable)
```